# How to secure a rail butting up to the wall

Tags: wood, safety, fastener, railing, handrail

I am out of ideas on how to fasten this rail butting up to the wall. I don't think that using a bracket would give it enough strength if someone were to lean on it as its span is 6 feet and so there's a lot of torque. (Besides, a bracket would look ugly.) There is plenty of lumber behind the drywall (two sheets of 3/4 plywood) so there would be plenty of bite for a screw.

[image]

Comment: Six feet? Is the other end causing problems? if it is this is the wrong place to try to fix it.

Comment: what size of wood is in the picture?

Comment: 2.5" x 1" white oak

Answer (score 4):

Any type of anchor/bracket at one end is not enough, unless there is more support along the length/other end.  Six feet makes a good lever.

With good wood behind, a couple of good size screws driven into both sides should hold.

A bracket either under or on the outside will give more holding power.  Brass brackets should look decent with that wood.

Answer (score 2):

If you have good wood behind that drywall and don't want a visible bracket, I'd say that's a good use for a pocket screw.

[image]

Picture is of a random pocket-hole kit from the Internet, but they all use the same principles.  The hole is drilled at a 15-degree angle to the joint with a dual-diameter drill bit, then a screw is inserted into the large hole, passing through the smaller hole into the wood.  Fill what's left with either dowel finished to match or wood putty.